# Maven tests run twice when a profile identifier is in multiple projects. Why?

Tags: maven, testing, intellij-idea

I have numerous projects in IntelliJ, each of which has a pom.xml, and each of the projects' poms inherit from the master pom.xml.  One profile (called test1) is present in two of the poms (for project2 and project4).  When I run maven from the command line, specifying one project and the profile name, it works (the tests in that project are executed once)  Here is the commmand:

```
mvn test -pl project2 -am -P test1
```

When I specify both projects (both of which have the same profile present), the tests in project4 are executed twice.  Here is the command:

```
mvn test -pl project2,project4 -am -P test1
```

I would like the tests only to be executed once.  I am running maven 3.1.1.

As a further complication, when I specify just project4, the tests in project2 get executed once, and the tests in project4 don't get executed at all.  Here is the command:

```
mvn test -pl project4 -am -P test1
```

Here is pom.xml for project2:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<project xmlns stuff...>
    <parent>
        <artifactId>parent artifact id</artifactId>
        <groupId>group id</groupId>
        <version>version</version>
    </parent>
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <name>project2</name>

    <artifactId>project2</artifactId>
    <packaging>jar</packaging>

    <profiles>
        <profile>
            <id>test1</id>
            <build>
                <plugins>
                    <plugin>
                        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                        <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
                        <version>2.9</version>
                        <executions>
                            <execution>
                                <id>execute-tests-1</id>
                                <phase>test</phase>
                                <goals>
                                    <goal>test</goal>
                                </goals>
                                <configuration>
                                    <skip>false</skip>
                                    <excludes>
                                        <exclude>com/path/to/exclude/**/*.java</exclude>
                                    </excludes>
                                </configuration>
                            </execution>
                        </executions>
                    </plugin>
                </plugins>
            </build>
        </profile>
    </profiles>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <!-- We don't want to run any tests without an active profile -->
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.9</version>
                <configuration>
                    <skip>true</skip>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <!-- This exports the classes in the tests for use with our other modules' tests -->
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-jar-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.2</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>test-jar</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

    <dependencies>
        [ dependencies ...]
    </dependencies>
</project>
```

Here is the pom.xml for project4:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<project xmlns stuff>
    <parent>
        <artifactId>[parent artifact id]</artifactId>
        <groupId>[group id]</groupId>
        <version>[version]</version>
    </parent>
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <name>project4</name>


    <artifactId>project4</artifactId>
    <packaging>jar</packaging>
    <dependencies>
        [ dependencies ...]
    </dependencies>

    <profiles>
        <profile>
            <id>test1</id>
            <build>
                <plugins>
                    <plugin>
                        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                        <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
                        <version>2.9</version>
                        <executions>
                            <execution>
                                <id>execute-tests-2</id>
                                <phase>test</phase>
                                <goals>
                                    <goal>test</goal>
                                </goals>
                                <configuration>
                                    <includes>
                                        <include>com/path/to/tests/*.java</include>
                                    </includes>
                                </configuration>
                            </execution>
                        </executions>
                    </plugin>
                </plugins>
            </build>
            <dependencies>
                [ dependencies...]
            </dependencies>
        </profile>
    </profiles>
</project>
```

Answer (score 4):

I figured out the answer to my own question (by looking carefully at some of our other projects' Maven test setup).  I had to do two things:

1. Include a `<skip>false</skip>` element in the `<configuration>` aggregate in the surefire plugin.
2. Include a generic surefire `<plugins>` aggregate outside of the `<profiles>` section.  This one has `<skip>` set to `true` and prevents tests being run unless they are in a profile.  Here is what the section looks like:

   ```
   <build>
       <plugins>
           <!-- We don't want to run any tests without an active profile -->
           <plugin>
               <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
               <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
               <version>2.9</version>
               <configuration>
                   <skip>true</skip>
               </configuration>
           </plugin>

       </plugins>
   </build>
   ```

   The problem was that the tests were running the default-test lifecycle phase and then they were running again in the test phase.  After I made the change they only ran in the test phase.

Comment: Why even add the surefire-plugin outside the profile at all if it's skipped anyway?